# What do you call a man who knows well how to fix his household appliances?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

Some men are really good at fixing things, especially household appliances (though they're not really specialists or technicians). Are there any words to describe or refer to these people?

Comment: You might call him *marriageable*.

Comment: @onomatomaniak, one can argue that if you'd marry him, you will never see brand new anything for the rest of your life.

Comment: https://youtu.be/dXI43zGeyu4

Answer (score 49, accepted):

*Handy*, which is something I'm not. (Just ask my wife...) MW says:

> clever in using the hands especially in a variety of convenient ways
>   [a man who is *handy* around the house]

Comment: But seldom applied to women, I think. 'A handy woman' suggests something altogether different.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: _Handy_ without man or woman attached suffices. I had a girlfriend who was handy; she made furniture, and kept her BMW 2002 in tune...

Comment: Hmm, you mean "handy woman" has some sort of unsavory meaning? I've never heard that. Maybe my sheltered life has again saved me from confronting unpleasantness! I just did a google search on "handy woman" and the results all seemed to be women doing handyman work, and cleaning and housekeeping services, which I guess some take as the female equivalent of being a handyman.

Comment: @Gnawme: Well, but "handy" is an adjective. You can say, "I need someone handy to fix this toaster", but you wouldn't say, "Fred got a job as a handy."

Comment: The "handy" in "handy woman" to me suggests "nearby" :)

Comment: @Jay - in BE a "handy women" would mean one that was conveniently present just when you really needed a women - like a "handy ladder" or a "handy cup of tea". Even "handyman" has a bit of a snigger factor

Comment: @Jay: OP: "Is there any words to explain these kind of men?" Answer: Yes, they are _handy_.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: Interesting, I didn't know that. Another expression to avoid in the UK. (Like walking into a pub and announcing, "Oh, I'm stuffed" thinking that you're stating that you overate...)

Comment: @Gnawme - "stuffed" means full of food in northern England. Just don't ask if you have to go outside to "suck on a fag" ;-)

Comment: I didn't mean that 'handy woman' was necessarily widely understood in BrEng to mean anything suggestive, but Martin expresses my meaning well.

Comment: "If the women don't find you handsome, they should at least find you handy." (from the Red Green show) Meaning that you should be able to fix or build things.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with being a woman; it depends on whether the adjective is before the noun or not. A "handy person" or "handy woman" is somebody who is nearby. A "person who is handy" or "woman who is handy" is somebody who can fix things.

Answer (score 29):

The person is called a "handyman".

> A handyman is a person skilled at a wide range of repairs, typically around the home.

<sup>From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handyman)</sup>

Comment: Well, there's a subtlety there. I think "handy man" -- two words -- normally refers to any man who is skilled at fixing things around the house. But "handyman" -- one word -- is an occupation, someone who does minor repairs and upgrades for a living.

Comment: @Jay Not necessarily.  From that same article, "The term handyman increasingly describes a paid worker, but it also includes non-paid homeowners or do-it-yourselfers."

Answer (score 8):

**Jack of all trades**, **odd-job man** might be synonyms of **handyman**.

Answer (score 8):

Other more formal solutions:

- Maintenance worker *
- Maintenance man
- Repairman
- Service man
- Repairer *

Other potential creative solutions:

- Fixer-upper *
- Mr. Fix-it
- DIY expert *
- DIYer * *(term presented by Izkata)*
- Handy Andy
- Handy Mandy ** *(term created by rachet freak)*

*Gender neutral terms are marked with an asterisk* *

*Gender female terms are marked with two asterisks* **

Comment: Handy Mandy for the females ;)

Comment: I would be wary of calling someone a "fixer-upper" -- to me that means they have something wrong with themselves, since I usually hear, e.g., "that house is a fixer-upper".

Comment: Ah, but that's all about how you use the sentence and the context surrounding it. If we are talking about insane asylums, yes, that would be a legitimate interpretation of the sentence. However, if I said, "This house has so much wrong with it, good thing Mandy is such a good fixer-upper", I think the meaning is clear. (+1 on Handy Mandy btw)

Comment: +1, I also see "DIYer" in those circles online on occasion