# What do you call someone who is good at everything?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a single word to describe someone who is good at everything? From a full variety of things... athletics, academics, even crafts & mechanics... one of those people who seems to have natural talent and drive for everything & almost seams to have the Midas touch?

Comment: I think this question is sufficiently more detailed and different in its emphasis to remain open.

Comment: Also sufficiently close to [What is another word for all-round capabilities?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48985/what-is-another-word-for-all-round-capabilities) etc to warrant closure. The same word families are being trotted out here.

Comment: 'jack of all trades'

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are describing a ***polymath*** (synonymous with ***polyhistor***):

> A **polymath** (Greek: πολυμαθής, polymathēs, "having learned much")<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath)</sup> is a person whose expertise spans a significant number of different subject areas; such a person is known to draw on complex bodies of knowledge to solve specific problems.
>   <sub>1.  The term was first recorded in written English in the early seventeenth century Harper, Daniel (2001). "Online Etymology Dictionary". Retrieved 2006-12-05.</sub>
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath)</sub>

Comment: multi-talented . . .